# Подписание клиентского запроса в JAVA

Tags: java, x509certificate

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь отправить https запрос и получить ответ от сервера с использованием .p12 сертификата:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
HttpRequest<String> httpRequest = HttpRequestBuilder.create(GET,"https://site.ru/",String.class).proxy("myproxy",pyport).build();
        String responseHandler = httpRequest.execute().get();
        System.out.println(responseHandler);
```

Добавляю сертификат через protecle: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Собственно сам сертификат состоит из 2-х страниц - если я правильно понимаю - это открытый и закрытый ключи.

Проблема в том, что java добавляет его как trusted (adding as trusted cert: в логе - при чем, я нахожу только 1 сертификат из двух по Serial number) но к самому запросу не добавляет.

Пытался отправлять запрос (через SSLSocket) и добавлять сертификат (через System.properties) различными способами - постоянно выдает ошибку Connection refused.

Единственное, чего я добился - это экспортировать одну из страниц через protecle (любую) из сертификата как PEM-файл и добавить его также в cacaers моей jdk
в таком случае ошибки следующие:

Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication

400 No required SSL certificate was sent

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с похожей проблемой?

---

@Темка тоже

В продолжение на Ваш ответ:

код на Powershell:

```
$certPath = "path"
$certPass = "password"
$Url = "https://ftp.mysite.domen.ru/" 
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}

$Cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certPath,$certPass)

$req = [system.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($Url)            

$req.ClientCertificates.AddRange($Cert)

$response = $req.GetResponse() #ОК
```

Ваш приведенный код дал также connection refused

Сам код + stacktrace (уже на Java):

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myproxyhost.ru");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "myproxyport");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "d:\\path\\to\\key\\$131001.p12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "keypassword");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "c:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-10.0.2\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");

String url = "https://ftp.mysite.domen.ru/" ;
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
GetMethod method = new GetMethod();
method.setPath(url);
int statusCode = httpclient.executeMethod(method);
System.out.println("Status: " + statusCode);
method.releaseConnection();
method.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

Stacktrace:

```
авг. 09, 2018 9:21:19 ДП org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
авг. 09, 2018 9:21:19 ДП org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
авг. 09, 2018 9:21:20 ДП org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
авг. 09, 2018 9:21:20 ДП org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
авг. 09, 2018 9:21:21 ДП org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
авг. 09, 2018 9:21:21 ДП org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:148)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:657)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:467)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at rti.EntryPoint_.main(EntryPoint_.java:53)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

У меня есть только предположение, что проблемы связаны с тем, что после протокола https:// стоит ftp, что, как я могу предположить, предполагает собой ftp over https, но я не уверен в этом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было найдено.

Проблемы, которые я проглядел:

1. Если у вас стоит прокси и необходимо добавлять System.Property, то для https-запроса вместо

   System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myproxyhost.ru");

   System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "myproxynumber");

нужно использовать

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "myproxyhost.ru");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "myproxynumber");
```

Также, необходимо использовать следующие property:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "d:\\path\\to\\keystore\\cert.p12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "keypassword");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "c:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-10.0.2\\lib\\security\\cacerts"); //можно не устанавливать, если стоит по умолчанию, необходимо обратить внимание на stacktrace: trustStore is: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\lib\security\cacerts trustStore type is: JKS
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

Плюс ко всему этому, **очень важное замечание** (возможно это только для моего случая): как я ни пытался добавлять p12 сертификат в cacerts, это не работало.
В итоге что я сделал: зашел через браузер на целевой сайт (предварительно установив сертификат в браузер) нажал слева от пути на "сертификат" - и копировал его в файл в кодировке BASE-64 в формате .cer. Далее, через утилиту portecle открыл свой cacerts и сделал "Import trusted certificates" моего .cer сертификата. Только после этого я получил ответ от сервера. 
Решение по этой проблеме нашел здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Код целиком:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "myproxyhost.ru");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "myproxynumber");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "d:\\path\\to\\keystore\\cert.p12");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "keypassword");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "c:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-10.0.2\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");

    URL url1 = new URL("https://ftp.my.site.ru/");
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
    connection.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String urlString = "";
    String current;
    while ((current = in.readLine()) != null) {
        urlString += current;
    }
    System.out.println(urlString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Информации в твоём вопросе недостаточно, желательно привести лог ошибки со стэктрейсом. Однако судя по текущему описанию, ты пытаешься подписать именно **клиентский запрос**. Если  это так, то тебе кидает ошибку, что не может найти подходящий сертификат в твоём хранилище. Привожу пример отправки подписанного клиентского запроса (оригинал [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10982796/5506820)).

```
String getHttpResponseWithSSL(String url) throws Exception {
    {
    //В блоке переопределяется хранилище доверенных сертификатов. По умолчанию это $JRE_HOME/lib/security/cacerts
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/securitycacerts");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
    }
    //my certificate and password
    {
    //В блоке определяется хранилище с сертификатами (и ключами) для подписание клиентской (твоей) стороны. Значения по умолчанию не имеет
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "mycert.pfx");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "mypass");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
     }

    //Дальше отправка запроса 
    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

    GetMethod method = new GetMethod();
    method.setPath(url);

    int statusCode = httpclient.executeMethod(method);
    System.out.println("Status: " + statusCode);

    method.releaseConnection();

    return method.getResponseBodyAsString();
}
```

P.S. Если я угадал, то переименуй вопрос в "Подписание клиентского запроса в JAVA"

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Действительно, возможно Вы правы на счет того, что именно я хочу. Дело в том, что данный код реализован через Powershell, который работает хорошо и, честно говоря, я сам не особо пойму, что нужно сделать.
В ответе ниже я опишу более подробно, т.к. тут не хватит места.